# How to find a probability that sum of geometric variables is less than a number

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be Geometric i.i.d random variables, which represent the number of fails,  with parameter $p$.

Calculate or estimate from above and below:
$$
P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\leq A), \quad A \in N.
$$

I know that sum of the geometric random variables is the negative binomial, but I would not know all the parameters for the negative binomial r.v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean $A \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $A$ is a natural number. You should probably use CLT here, as $n$ is large, $X_i$ are iid with $\mu <\infty, \sigma^2<\infty$
$$
P(S_n<A) = P(\frac{S_n-n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}<\frac{A-n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}) \approx \Phi(z)
$$
Here $z = \frac{A-n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$, and $\mu, \sigma$ are mean and sd of each $X_i$, which you can easily find.